# Correct Syntax to add Hyperlinks to Excel Worksheet from an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, hyperlink

I have an Excel macro which uses DIR in a lopp to retrieve all files from all folders and displays them on a worksheet. The bit of code which outputs to the worksheet on each iteration is:

```
rOut.Range("A1:B1").Offset(iFile).Value = Array(sName, sFile)
```

I would like to output the first cell as a hyperlink to the folder the file is located in (stored in variable sPath), and in the second cell I would like to output the filename, which is also a hyperlink to open the file.

I came up with this bit of code:

```
With rOut
    With .Cells(1, 1)
        .Offset(iFile).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Offset(iFile), Address:=sPath, TextToDisplay:=sName
    End With
    With .Cells(1, 2)
        .Offset(iFile).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Offset(iFile), Address:=sName, TextToDisplay:=sFile
    End With
End With
```

I know this is sloppy, and it is markedly slower than the above array syntax, but I just can't figure it out.

Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Figure what out?  Do you get an error? The code you posted isn't "sloppy" - that's just how hyperlinks are created.  You *could* assign both at once if you use something like `rOut.Range("A1:B1").Offset(iFile).Formula = Array(hyperlinkFormula1, hyperlinkFormula1)` but that's not really any improvement, just a lot of string concatenation.

Comment: No errors, I was just looking to concatenate, Tim, thanks. How would I declare hyperlinkFormula1, though?

Comment: As an array of strings e.g. `Array("=HYPERLINK(""urlHere"", ""textHere"")", "=HYPERLINK(""url2Here"", ""text2Here"")")`